# .hover() anchor element and show hide a secondary

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="navbar-header">   
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ URL::route('admin.pages.index') }}">Laravel Admin</a> 
 <a class="slideout-toggle" href='/'>visit site</a>
</div>


<script>
    jQuery(".slideout-toggle").hide();
    jQuery(".navbar-brand").hover(
        function(){
            jQuery(".slideout-toggle").show();
        }, 
        function(){
            jQuery(".slideout-toggle").hide();
        }

    );
</script>
```

Of course when the mouse stops hovering `.navbar-brand` - `.hide()` kicks in. But 'visit site' disappears before I can click it. How can I make it clickable? 
So hover `.navbar-brand` my `slideout-toggle` anchor element displays *and* I'm allowed to click it!

I guess my choice of events is incorrect.

Comment: Works - @isherwood - the span is higher up the tree or is a parent of the anchor hence delaying the hide() method. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting the hover event on the anchor, put both anchors in an element, such as a span or div, and apply the hover to that element.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/hs4nU/

```
<div id="link-wrapper"> 
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ URL::route('admin.pages.index') }}">Laravel Admin</a>  
    <br />
    <a class="slideout-toggle" href='/'>visit site</a>
</div>


$(".slideout-toggle").hide();

$("#link-wrapper").hover(function () {
    $(".slideout-toggle").slideDown();
},
function () {
    $(".slideout-toggle").slideUp();
});
```

The hover function can actually be simplified like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/hs4nU/2/

```
$("#link-wrapper").hover(function () {
    $(".slideout-toggle").slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for JS:

```
.navbar-header > .slideout-toggle{
    display: none;
}
.navbar-header:hover > .slideout-toggle{
    display: inline;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k9jjM/